# Acquire a list of printers from within a browser session?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, printing

I am writing a web application that requires the ability to see the list of printers that are connected to the clients machine. I would like to know if there is any known solution available from withing the browser that does not require Active X or IE. Also, installing a mini server or script on the client's machine is not a viable solution. My target browsers are Chrome and Firefox. I simply want the list and am not searching for the ability to spool print jobs to the printer.

Comment: This is an OS-level function. Browsers are isolated from this type of OS interaction to specifically keep them from snooping things like this. You would need to make a browser extension or use Flash.

Comment: Does flash provide the list of all printers connected to the client system, or simply perform the same functionality as window.print() allowing the user to select which printer?

Comment: Dunno, never done it. I just know it's certainly not going to be thenbrowser.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane "_This is an OS-level function._" No it isn't. It's an application level issue. Windows applications do list printers (or they just don't and let the OS default dialog handle that). Google Chrome Windows proposes printing directly from a browser window (not std the old ugly Windows print dialog).

Comment: Do you want your browser to expose your printer to random strangers on the net?